# Plato's allegory of the cave and addiction -snippet of New York Times article:What will it take to motivate those to come out who stayed inside cave?

Tags: plato

I read a wonderful article on Plato's allegory of cave and addiction by Peg O'Connor titled **In the Cave: Philosophy and Addiction**. This article was published in the New York Times Newspaper. There she wrote and I quote a snippet of it:

"A sort of recognition may be found in examining allegory, in this case, a very familiar one from Plato. Allegory — a story that functions as an extended metaphor and has both literal and figurative meanings — is clearly not science. But it does offer the potential for a sort of insight that conceptual analysis can not. An allegory allows us to unpack many of those dimensions that escape more scientific description. With the cave allegory that Plato offers in the “Republic” to draw the line between appearance and reality, we have a potentially powerful tool for understanding the crisis of the addicted person. Briefly, Plato’s allegory is this:

There is a cave in which prisoners are chained facing a wall. They cannot move their heads and therefore cannot look sideways or behind; they only can look forward. Behind them are a burning fire and a half wall where puppeteers hold up puppets that cast shadows. To the chained men, the shadows are real; they have no conception of the objects that cause the shadows. Appearance is mistaken for reality, and thus there is no real knowledge.

Now imagine that the prisoners are released from their chains. They look behind them and see the objects that caused the shadows. Most likely they will be confused and horrified and unwilling to accept that these objects caused the shadows. Imagine now that the prisoners start to leave the cave. They will be painfully blinded as soon as they encounter light. Once their eyes begin to adjust, they will be confronted by a harsh bright world with a whole host of horrifying objects. Some of the men will flee back to the safety of the darkness and shadows, valuing the familiar more highly than the unfamiliar. Anyone who returns and tells his friends who are still enchained what he has seen will be regarded as a nut lacking any credibility. Other men, once their eyes have more fully adjusted to the light, will want to stay above ground. Such people come to realize that world of light is the real one where genuine knowledge is possible. One further point to consider: some of the people who have seen the light of truth and reality need to go into the cave to help those who are still enchained to leave the cave. This is the philosopher’s burden, according to Plato.

This allegory is richly wonderful for understanding addiction, relapse and recovery. Most people who become addicted become enchained to their drug of choice. The word “addiction” comes from the Latin verb “addicere,” which means to give over, dedicate or surrender. In the case of many alcoholics, for instance, including my own, this is just what happens. What had perhaps started as fun and harmless use begins to grow troubling, painful and difficult to stop. The alcoholic becomes chained to alcohol in a way different from others who “drink normally.”

In various scenarios of addiction, the addicted person’s fixation on a shadow reality — one that does not conform to the world outside his or her use — is apparent to others. When the personal cost of drinking or drug use becomes noticeable, it can still be written off or excused as merely atypical. Addicts tend to orient their activities around their addictive behavior; they may forego friends and activities where drinking or drug use is not featured. Some may isolate themselves; others may change their circle of friends in order to be with people who drink or use in the same way they do. They engage in faulty yet persuasive alcoholic reasoning, willing to take anything as evidence that they do not have a problem; no amount of reasoning will persuade them otherwise. Each time the addict makes a promise to cut down or stop but does not, the chains get more constricting.

Yet for many reasons, some people begin to wriggle against the chains of addiction. Whether it is because they have experiences that scare them to death (not uncommon) or lose something that really matters (also not uncommon), some people begin to work themselves out of the chains. People whose descent into addiction came later in life have more memories of what life can be like sober. Some will be able to turn and see the fire and the half wall and recognize the puppets causing the shadows. Those whose use started so young that it is all they really know will often experience the fear and confusion that Plato described. But as sometimes happens in recovery, they can start to come out of the cave, too.

The brightness of the light can be painful, as many alcoholic or drug dependent people realize once their use stops. Those who drank or used drugs to numb feelings or avoid painful memories may feel defenseless. This is why they will retreat back to the familiar darkness of the cave. Back with their drinking friends, they will find comfort. This is one way to understand relapse.

Others will make it farther out of the cave and have their eyes adjust. They will struggle to stay sober and balanced. So many of their old coping behaviors will not work, and they are faced with a seemingly endless task of learning how to rebuild their emotional lives. Some will stay clean and sober for a good while and later relapse. People relapse for all sorts of reasons, and often these have to do with old patterned ways of thinking and behaving that make a roaring comeback. When people who have had some sobriety relapse and go back to the darkness of the cave, they may be met with derision ― an “I told you so” attitude.

Those who do make it out of the cave and manage never to relapse again are few and far between. They know just how precarious their sobriety is and what they need to do to maintain it. People with long-term sobriety are often the ones who need to go back down into the cave, not as saviors, but for their own survival. People with years of sobriety often say that newcomers help them to stay sober because their pain, loss, and confusion are so fresh. Their stories remind old timers of enchained life in the cave. Old timers can share their stories too and in the process show them different ways to be in the world.

Of course, our stories are real and deeply personal, but like allegories they can wield a transformative power. Transformation can come from many sources, including some of the earliest and most profound investigations in philosophy. Plato’s cave, Montaigne’s cat, Kierkegaard’s leap of faith, Nietzsche’s myth of eternal recurrence, Wittgenstein’s fly in the fly bottle, and feminist conceptions of self-identity — to name but a few — are ready companions in the pursuit to understand the complexities of addiction, relapse and recovery."

My question those who stayed inside the cave forever can they never see the light of hope that is awaiting them outside the cave? What does drive them or motivate them to stay in that poor deplorable state? Don't they ever wish to come out?

I ask this because I met a case manager with whom I had the opportunity to speak about people who are constricted by homelessness and addiction but actually and he said if some of them really work hard can come out of it. For example, they left subsidized apartments and the best job offers and still living in the streets.

So just wanted to know, those who had stayed behind inside the cave and never came out or had come out but didn't like it what can motivate them to save themselves?

I know Homo Sapiens have free will. But those who stayed behind their rationality are polluted and corrupted by years of degradation of substance abuse namely alcohol. They are not into themselves. Plato implicitly meant that it is the free will of the people in the cave that will make them free. But their free will is controlled by substances. How can they make a rational and logical decision? And that is why I am asking this question. And don't we call people with substance abuse ill because addiction is an illness just like mental illness?

Comment: [Here's](https://www.vox.com/the-big-idea/2018/3/5/17080470/addiction-opioids-moral-blame-choices-medication-crutches-philosophy) an interesting article by a philosopher discussing addiction and the degree to which addicts can be blamed for the choices, he argues addictions are illustrations of the way the "self" is "not a single, unitary thing" but rather involves a struggle between different mental systems with different goals, and that "The messy truth about addiction is that it lies somewhere in between choice and compulsion".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have struggled with drug and alcohol abuse for nearly 2 decades. Even having been diagnosed with multiple medical issues due to alcohol, which will kill me, did not help me to decide sobriety was important. I was willing to "stay in the cave." I only just recently decided to seriously attempt sobriety. I was on a destructive path that I used as an excuse to justify using even more. I ended up finding a purpose and something that I could re-direct my energy into. I am immensely grateful for it, I was an entirely different person when I was high or drunk. I believe the path to recovery is specifically unique, and tailored to every individual, but of course there are common threads interwoven with addiction / recovery that are simply universally identifiable. I feel one of the most important is having to be tired of the cycle, and willing to try even if at first you don't succeed, never give up. I really enjoyed this post as I had never heard that story before and love philosophy, so thank you for sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can help is by investing much more in public services and educating people in public-spiritedness rather than mean-mindedness.

This will mean giving economics a complete reshaping as it is predicated in the pure selfishness of man, or what they term as homo economicus, the purely rational agent.

It also means renewing the meaning and the purpose of the academy which in the neo-liberal regime has come under enormous stress and change to the extent they think of the academy as merely another profit-centre and their students as customers and their teaching, lecturing and research staff as expendable adjuncts that don't always know their place.